# IntelliJ 13 complaining about an 'unescaped xml character' in inline script

Tags: javascript, html, xml, angularjs, intellij-idea

IntelliJ's inspector is underlining the body of the script tag.
Who is doing something wrong me or it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="_template/company.inline">

    <g:render template="/shared/header"/>
    <g:render template="/shared/nav"/>

            <section id="content">
                <section class="main padder" app-view-segment="1"></section>
            </section>

</script>
```

So is this a valid xml? And I do not required to wrap this with cdata or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known bug in the lasts EAP versions (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9833). It is fixed now so it should appears soon in a next EAP version.