# Wrong IntelliJ warning about unescaped characters for xml <script> element

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, script-tag, code-inspection

I have a XML file that looks like

```
<script>
    <foo>bar</foo>
</script>
```

This is no HTML and the the `<script>` tag has nothing to do with the [HTML script tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp). (Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157513/intellij-13-complaining-about-an-unescaped-xml-character-in-inline-script))

But IntelliJ (Version 2016.2) wrongly displays warnigs about unescaped XML characters for the first bracket of the sub elements of `<script>`. Mistakes IntelliJ this for the HTML script tag? How can I prevent that?

The warnings appear regardless of the presence of an header like `<?xml version="1.0" ?>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug see [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115848) .According to [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9833) thread you can try turning Inspections/HTML/Malformed content of `<script>` tag off.

Comment: The bug you linked is a duplicate of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9833 which is marked as fixed. But of course, disabling the inspection helps, thanks for that!